# How to Access Splash Screen Specified in JNLP?

Tags: java, splash-screen, jnlp

I have specified splash picture in jnlp application

```
<icon href="starter.png" kind="splash"/>
```

When I use IE to run the jnlp, the splash window showed up, but my application can't access the splash.  I have used the static variable to obtain the instance:

```
private static SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
```

in main(), I first check whether splash is null, and unfortunately, it is null.  Then why can I see it for a few seconds?  Did Java Web Start window closed it?

If I run application (not jnlp) in Eclipse with vm arguments then I can access the splash screen and update my slow loading process.

How do I access the splash screen using jnlp?

Answer (score 0):

The splash screen as used by web start predates the AWT `SplashScreen`  API & is not compatible with it.

> How do I access the splash screen using jnlp?

It cannot be accessed.

---

> ..it looks like I have to pop up a window to show the picture.

I'd say that is the only option.

> ..But that way there is no way to show transparency with the splash screen at least before Java 7, right?

Correct.  Given that..

> ..I mean, I don't want to use the reflection either.

..well, reaching into Sun(/Oracle) private classes is not necessarily 'reflection', I guess that is your worry, and that worry is well founded.  Either give up on a partially transparent splash, or wait for Java 7.

But then, gotta' comment, I've *never* before seen a semi-transparent splash.  If a splash is worth showing, why *not* show it at full opacity?

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, it looks like I have to pop up a window to show the picture.  But that way there is no way to show transparency with the splash screen at least before Java 7, right?  I mean, I don't want to use the reflection either.